# ASP.net MVC 3 can i replace all <%= in my views with <%:?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms-view-engine

i have an MVC 3 site using asp.net 4

in my views i have used `<%=` for outputting data.

reading this post by phil haack -> http://haacked.com/archive/2009/09/25/html-encoding-code-nuggets.aspx

He suggests that <%= should be a distant memory, as long as your using .net 4.

i have done a find and replace all, on one of my views replacing

```
<%= to <%:
```

and everything works as normal.

so my question, can i go ahead and do a global replace on all my views? are there any issues to be aware of ?

Truegilly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful though as if you have something like this:

```
<%= Html.Encode(Model.Foo) %>
```

you might get double encoding when you end up with:

```
<%: Html.Encode(Model.Foo) %>
```

Whereas the correct would be:

```
<%: Model.Foo %>
```

Personally I tend to always use:

```
<%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Foo) %>
```

So, it's not as easy as a simple search & replace. There might be some breaking modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Everything that [Darin said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256302/asp-net-mvc-3-can-i-replace-all-in-my-views-with/7256481#7256481) and this:

#### After-format with HTML

Be aware when you after format your output and add some HTML inside it as in

```
<%= this.Model.Explanation.Replace("\n", "<br/>") %>
```

This clearly won't work after you'd simply replace `<%=` with `<%:`.